# How Can I get all products under a parent category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 types of categories

- parent category hasMany() child categories
- Child hasMany Portfolios

now I want to show All portfolios using category

Category.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function portfolios()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Portfolio::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Portfolio.php

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

for this I get everything.

```
$portfolio = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('categories.portfolios')->get();
```

dd($portfolio)

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => App\Category {#1229 ▶}
  1 => App\Category {#1230 ▶}
  2 => App\Category {#1231 ▶}
  3 => App\Category {#1232 ▼
    #table: "categories"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #fillable: array:3 [▶]
    #attributes: array:6 [▶]
    #original: array:6 [▶]
    #relations: array:1 [▼
      "portfolios" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1228 ▼
        #items: array:1 [▼
          0 => App\Portfolio {#1240 ▼
            #table: "portfolios"
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #fillable: array:4 [▶]
           
            #attributes: array:7 [▶]
            #original: array:7 [▶]
            
            #relations: []
            
            #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
 
  }
]
```

Now how can I show all portfolios from this in 1 array or 1 collection? kindly help...

Comment: You aren't creating a great visual representation here. It would be best if you edited the question with your models. But my guess is what you probably need is pluck('products')

Comment: yes I need pluck ('products') but it returns me null

Comment: kindly show your models and probably migration files

Comment: I need to pluck those products which are under Child categories

Comment: ok. give me a sec I updating my question

Comment: updated my question. please have a look

Comment: The problem here is how you have defined your relationships

Comment: I think relationships are okay. I already did create update and delete. But In show It returns like this. 
1. category has 2 child. (returns 2 array).
2. 1st child has 3 products, 2nd child has 2 products ( returns inside relations array.) 

I need only total products. like 3+2= 5 products. means 1 collections with 5 products under this conditions.

Comment: see now. I edited my questions. with dd()

Comment: I still don't see anything related to products not even in dd(). Not sure if this will work but you could try `Category::with('categories.portfolios')->get()->pluck('products');`

Comment: sorry IT is not products, it portfolios. Products means portfolios.

Comment: sorry it was typing mistake. It should be portfolios, not products. I think now you can Understand.

Comment: Please check now. I edited all products to portfolios.

Comment: Category::with('portfolios')->get()->pluck('portfolios')

Comment: It gives me all null value.

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1206 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1222 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1211 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1216 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1217 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    4 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1210 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    5 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1229 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
}

Comment: all arrays items are null / []